# Java formatting a arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

I got an Arraylist that looks like this

```
[netl, entl, ltc, 6.3, 6.3, maat, lo, CombiGym, mr, wisB, nat, schk, biol, 6.4, 6.4, wisD, L&W, 9, 8.5, reken, exp]
```

I want it to look like this

```
[netl, entl, ltc 6.3 6.3, maat, lo, CombiGym, mr, wisB, nat, schk, biol 6.4 6.4, wisD, L&W 9 8.5, reken, exp]
```

I dont want the numbers to be a seperate object in the ArrayList.
This is my code

```
    ArrayList<String> arrayvakken = new ArrayList<String>();
    String loginFormUrl = "https://example.com/login?path=%2F%3F";
    String loginActionUrl = "https://example.com/login?passAction=login&path=%2F%3F";
    String username = "USERNAME";
    String password = "PASSWORD";

    HashMap<String, String> cookies = new HashMap<>();
    HashMap<String, String> formData = new HashMap<>();

    Connection.Response loginForm = Jsoup.connect(loginFormUrl).method(Connection.Method.GET).userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:56.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/56.0").execute();
    Document loginDoc = loginForm.parse(); // this is the document that contains response html

    cookies.putAll(loginForm.cookies()); // save the cookies, this will be passed on to next request


    formData.put("Login", "Inloggen");
    formData.put("wu_loginname", username);
    formData.put("wu_password", password);

    Connection.Response homePage = Jsoup.connect(loginActionUrl)
            .cookies(cookies)
            .data(formData)
            .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:56.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/56.0")
            .method(Connection.Method.POST)
            .execute();

    Document document2 = Jsoup.connect("https://example.com/Portaal/Cijfer_menu/Cijferoverzicht").cookies(cookies).get();
    for(Element element : document2.select(".vak,.wp3-cijfer")) {
        arrayvakken.add(element.select(".vak,.wp3-cijfer").text());
            }
    for(String str : arrayvakken) {
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([0-9])");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
        if(m.find()){
            System.out.println("number");
        } else {
            System.out.println("word");
        }
        
    }
        }
```

How would i format the ArrayList as shown at the top?

Comment: What does that code have to do with either of those arrays?

Comment: what is the type in the list??

Comment: String, I'm using Jsoup to get data from a website

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to guess what exactly you're trying to achieve. Assuming you've got an ArrayList containing Strings, the following code will probably do what you want to achieve (use the method updateList to change an ArrayList that looks like your first example into an ArrayList that looks like your second example):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("netl"); list.add("etnl"); list.add("ltc"); list.add("6.3"); list.add("6.3");
        list.add("maat"); list.add("lo"); list.add("CombiGym"); list.add("mr"); list.add("wisB");
        list.add("nat"); list.add("schk"); list.add("biol"); list.add("6.4"); list.add("6.4");
        list.add("wisD"); list.add("L&W"); list.add("9"); list.add("8.5"); list.add("reken");
        list.add("exp");
        log(list);
        log(updateList(list));
    }

    public static ArrayList<String> updateList(ArrayList<String> list)
    {
        ArrayList<String> ret = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i=0; i<list.size(); i++)
        {
            if (i == 0)
                ret.add(list.get(i));
            else
            {
                Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^[0-9]+(\\.[0-9]+)?$");
                Matcher m = p.matcher(list.get(i));
                if (m.find()) ret.set(ret.size()-1, ret.get(ret.size()-1) + " " + list.get(i));
                else ret.add(list.get(i));
            }
        }
        return ret;
    }

    public static void log(ArrayList<String> list)
    {
        String logstr = "[";
        for (int i=0; i<list.size(); i++)
        {
            if (i > 0) logstr += ", ";
            logstr += list.get(i);
        }
        logstr += "]";
        System.out.println(logstr);
    }
}
```

If I run the code above, I get the following output:

```
[netl, etnl, ltc, 6.3, 6.3, maat, lo, CombiGym, mr, wisB, nat, schk, biol, 6.4, 6.4, wisD, L&W, 9, 8.5, reken, exp]
[netl, etnl, ltc 6.3 6.3, maat, lo, CombiGym, mr, wisB, nat, schk, biol 6.4 6.4, wisD, L&W 9 8.5, reken, exp]
```

Comment: In your code, just replace the for(String str : arrayvakken)-loop with arrayvakken = updateList(arrayvakken); You oubviously have to copy the updateList method from my code sample to be able to use it.